# What is the purpose of 3ds Max mode?

Tags: customization

3ds Max mode doesn't seem to do what the name implies.  Could someone explain what exactly does it do?

Comment: It's about the navigation in 3D view.

Comment: What exactly does the name not imply? I think it's pretty fitting.

Answer (score 1):

In blender 2.79 in the splash screen and the input preferences you can find a choice between blender, Max3D and Maya. These are not "modes" but collections of keyboard shortcuts setup to mimic other 3D applications. They are to help users who are familiar with other software to start using blender without having to learn new shortcuts.

Comment: I expected more judging by the name, this is why i found it confusing.